# app not working in galaxy s3 and note 2

Tags: android, android-manifest

my app not working on galaxy s3 and note 2, here is my manifest code:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/cars"
    android:label="@string/appName"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="kazemi.Alireza.cardatabase.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/appName" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

what is the problem?Thanks

Comment: What does that mean "Not working"?

Comment: really, i am a developer and customers that buy my app,said that app not installed on galaxy s3 and note 2

Comment: You should have stacktraces in your Google Play Console

Comment: it doesn't due to targetsdk=15?

Comment: No, it's not an issue. Actually this attribute should be as higher as possible in general. So for now it should be 17.

Comment: unfortunately i don't know what is the problem, and my app is not publish on google, and i don't have the console

Comment: I guess the solution is to get one of these devices and find out what the problem is by yourself by testing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/cars"
    android:label="@string/appName"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="kazemi.Alireza.cardatabase.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/appName" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: just try now, android:targetSdkVersion="15" is not needed. Some Faults occurs on posting.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html can't see where they say it's not needed